# How to compute New West standard errors with time series data and fixest package

Tags: r, time-series

I have a dataframe consisting of a time series and I want to run Poisson quasi ML models using the `fixest` package. To account for autocorrelation of the error terms, I want to compute Newey West standard errors. However, so far, I have not managed to do that. Here is my code:

```
model1 <- feglm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 | x4,
                data, family = quasipoisson)
summary(model1, newey ~ time)
```

When I run the code I get the error message:

```
Error: in summary.fixest_multi(model1, newey ~ time):
 Argument 'type' must be a single character equal to 'short', 'long', 'compact' or
'se_compact'. Problem: it is not a vector, it is of class 'formula'.
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your `summary` call dispatches [`summary.fixest_multi`](https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/fixest/html/summary.fixest_multi.html), which second argument is `type=` whereas you probably want `cluster=`. You should use a named argument.

```
summary(model1, cluster=newey ~ time)
```

Comment: When I run your code, I get: ```Error in vcov.fixest(object, se = se, cluster = cluster, dof = dof, forceCovariance = forceCovariance,  :  If argument cluster is to be a formula, it must be one sided: e.g. ~fe_1+fe_2.```

I also tried ```summary(model1, vcov =newey ~ time)```. But this gives me the ordinary standard errors as in ```summary(model1)```.

Comment: @Paul Probably because `"time"` isn't included in your real data, try the name of the variable associated with time instead. BTW, you could make a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).